# Sanitizing all string values in a complex object?

Tags: javascript, string, sanitization

I have a `sanitizeStr()` function that I need to run on EVERY property/subproperty that exists in an object like the one below:

```
const data = {
  info: 'schools',
  schools: [
    { name: 'Johnson Elementary', type: 'elementary' },
    { name: 'Iselin Middle School', type: 'middle' }
  ],
  bestStudent: {
    name: 'John',
    grade: 'sixth'
  }
};
```

The issue is that for every single one of these properties, they may or may not exist. Right now, I'm having to do multiple `if` checks for each property and manually running the function:

```
// Is there a better way to do this rather than what I have here:

if (data.info) {
  data.info = sanitizeStr(data.info);
}

if (data.bestStudent) {
  if (data.bestStudent.name) {
    data.bestStudent.name = sanitizeStr(data.bestStudent.name);
  }

  if (data.bestStudent.grade) {
    data.bestStudent.grade = sanitizeStr(data.bestStudent.grade);
  }
}

if (data.schools) {
  data.schools.forEach((school, i) => {
    if (school.name) {
      data.schools[i].name = sanitizeStr(school.name);
    }

    if (school.grade) {
      data.schools[i].grade = sanitizeStr(school.grade);
    }
  });
}
```

If anyone knows of a cleaner/less manual way of doing this, it would be appreciated.

Comment: what is `sanitizeStr` doing? please add the function as well.

Comment: I didn't include it because I don't think it's quite relevant – It just does some string replacements. I'm basically just trying to figure out a better way to run that function on every property without having to do it one by one manually.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterate through object properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312459/iterate-through-object-properties)

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I'm aware of how to iterate through an object's properties. However, I can't just do a loop and run `sanitizeStr` on each prop in the loop because the property might be a string, an object, or an array of objects.

Comment: And you can't check the type before running `sanitizeStr` on a property? `typeof stringVar === 'string'`...

Comment: Well if the type is not a string, but an object, I want to traverse through that object as well and if its an array of objects I want to traverse through that array and traverse through each prop of each object in the array. So it's a bit more complicated than that. Nina's answer looks good tho

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use an iterative and recursive approach for objects and call the function for non objects only.

```js
function sanitizeStr(s) {
    return '#' + s;
}

function iterAll(object) {
    Object.keys(object).forEach(function (k) {
        if (object[k] && typeof object[k] === 'object') {
            iterAll(object[k]);
            return;
        }
        object[k] = sanitizeStr(object[k]);
    })
}

var data = { info: 'schools', schools: [{ name: 'Johnson Elementary', type: 'elementary' }, { name: 'Iselin Middle School', type: 'middle' }], bestStudent: { name: 'John', grade: 'sixth' } };

iterAll(data);

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: You may want to check for strings explicitly in order to avoid sanitizing numbers (thereby converting them to strings).  +1 in any case.

Comment: At this point in my code, if the properties DO exist they are guaranteed to be strings, but that's a useful comment in case anyone else sees this down the line. And thanks a lot, I think I can go with an approach like this.

Answer (score 0):

You must me looking for this

```js
const sanitizeObject = (obj, callBack, isClone = false) => {
    let tempObj = obj;
    if(typeof callBack === 'function' && (typeof tempObj === 'string' || typeof tempObj === 'number')){
      return callBack(tempObj)
    }else if(typeof tempObj === 'object' && tempObj !== null){
      tempObj = isClone ? (Array.isArray(tempObj) ? [...tempObj] : {...tempObj}) : tempObj;
      Object.keys(tempObj).forEach(objKey => {
        const valueOfobject = tempObj[objKey]
        if(typeof valueOfobject === 'string' || typeof valueOfobject === 'number'){
          tempObj[objKey] = callBack(tempObj[objKey])
        }else {
          tempObj[objKey] = sanitizeObject(valueOfobject, callBack, isClone)
        }
      })
    } 
    return tempObj;
}

const data = {
test1: {
  test2: [{
  property: "any string",
  property2: null
}]}
}

console.log(sanitizeObject(data, function (stringValue){
  return stringValue + " apend"
}))
```